# Hosting the production build css of nuxt app to CDN?

Tags: webpack, vue.js, nuxt.js

My Vue app(Nuxt) has several components with scoped css. We want all of our css to be minified into one file and then hosted over a CDN for better caching and less load on web server. 
Component A

```
<style scoped>
.a{
    background-color: blue;
}

</style>
```

Component B

```
  <style scoped>
  .b{
      background-color: red;
  }
  </style>
```

Is it possible to extract all these scoped file into a single file and then host over to CDN? If yes, how ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `extractCSS` option?

It should work given your components are not async.

https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#extractcss